# Neo4J APOC apoc.import.csv error

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to import Nodes & Relationships from .csv files into Neo4J using APOC.

While trying the example provided:

```
CALL apoc.import.csv(
  [{filename: 'file:/<path>/persons.csv', labels: ['Person']}],
  [{filename: 'file:/<path>/knows.csv', type: 'KNOWS'}],
  {delimiter: '|', arrayDelimiter: ',', stringIds: false}
)
```

I am getting error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.import.csv`: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
```

There is no stack trace to see the details of where it could be failing.

Please suggest what could i be missing?

Comment: I think it's a bug on the lib when we define a `delimiter` or/and an `arraydelimiter`. Can you open an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug that was not covered by the tests as they passed the delimiter values in Java. I submitted a fix and a test in a [pull request](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/pull/949).